# Working with Multiple Environments in .NET framework 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks

I use .NET Framework 4.7.2 Console application.
I want to switch between environments as easily as I do in projects on dotnet core using the launchSettings.json file, I created this file, but on the launch menu one environment ended up:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you created an old-style csproj? You'd be better off using an SDK-style csproj, which will respect launchSettings.json. Create a .NET Core console application, then change `<TargetFramework>` to `net472`

Comment: I have about 1000 lines in my old-style csproj file , is there any way to somehow migrate it to a new style?

Comment: There are plenty of articles online, and MS even released a tool. It depends on what your 1000 lines are: if they're adding .cs files, then that's done automatically in an SDK-style csproj so you won't need them.

Comment: ASP.NET 4.x does not support that, so you either write your own VS extension to enable that, or simply accept the lack of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by migrating the old *.csproj file.
This utility helped me: https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017